# Connecting Marketing Cloud BU to Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

I have a client who has two data sources 1) on-premise datawarehouse and 2) Salesforce CRM. I will be connecting the on-premise datawarehouse to the Parent Business Unit to pass data in child business units. I will then plan to connect Marketing Cloud and the Salesforce CRM to one of the child business units.

Are there any issues with this? All it means is that the Parent business unit won't be the master for configuring Salesforce CRM fields and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be an issue, however,  to do such a configuration you will need to enable Multi-Org Marketing Cloud Connect via SFMC Support. Which is a permanent SFMC Account config change that basically isolates all SFDC <> SFMC connections to each Business Unit in SFMC. So scalability and further expansion of any SFDC data is hindered. You can still connect all the BUs to the same SFDC Org, just takes time and redundancy.

Here's a document on how that all works if you are curious:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5

This is the only way to connect just a Child BU to a SFDC Org without it just inheriting it from the parent.